# What formula can I use in Google Sheets to find the lowest historic price of a stock?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-finance

I want to use Google Sheets to find the lowest price a stock has reached between two dates, or the lowest it has fallen in its life. I have tried various formulas but none have worked. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks,
Nick

Comment: Can you provide a copy of the sheet? As said in the answers the `MIN` or` MINIFS` functions should solve what you ask for. What formulas have you tried?

Comment: I've  tried =index(GOOGLEFINANCE("GOOG", "low", DATE(2004,8,18), TODAY()),2,2) but the result doesn't tally with any stock graph I've looked at. How would I use the MIN or MINIFs function in a formula?

Comment: This one works: =MIN(GOOGLEFINANCE ("GOOG", "LOW", TODAY ()-15, TODAY ())) However, I can't get it to work between two dates in the past, i.e. between 2004,8,18 and 2008,8,18.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the data so that the formula you are using can be checked? Also you can check [this](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/23964) aproximation: `=MIN(GoogleFinance("Goog", "PRICE", DATE(2004,8,18)))`

Answer (score 0):

i can't comment because of not enough reputation. you can try this below?

If you want to find the lowest price a stock has reached between two dates, you can use the following formula:

> =MIN(B2:BJ2)

If you want to find the lowest price a stock has fallen in its life, you can use the following formula:

> =MIN(B2:BJ2)*-1

The MIN function in Google Sheets can be used to find the minimum value between two dates.

Answer (score 0):

Use `MINIFS` function that will allow you to define the period.